# How to install serial port module on Node?

Tags: npm, node-modules, raspbian, node-serialport, orange-pi

I have a problem installing the serial module on Node. I am using Raspbian server for orange pi zero H2.

```
root@OrangePI:/home/node# npm install serialport
```

return

```
npm WARN package.json one@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json one@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json one@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN engine serialport@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current:     {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/parser-ready@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/binding-mock@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/parser-byte-length@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/stream@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/bindings@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/parser-readline@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/parser-regex@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/parser-delimiter@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/parser-cctalk@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/binding-abstract@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine @serialport/binding-abstract@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=8.6.0"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine prebuild-install@5.3.3: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine expand-template@2.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine decompress-response@4.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine mimic-response@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=8"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
npm WARN engine readable-stream@3.4.0: wanted: {"node":">= 6"} (current: {"node":"4.9.1","npm":"2.15.11"})
```

...

```
> @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings > prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild

/home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/node_modules/prebuild-install/node_modules/simple-get/index.js:18
const { hostname, port, protocol, auth, path } = url.parse(opts.url) // eslint-disable-line node/no-deprecated-api
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/node_modules/prebuild-install/download.js:3:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I have little experience in linux ... but is it my impression or is the declared constant really unnamed?

```
make: Entering directory 
'/home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build'
    CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bindings/src/serialport.o
make: g++: Command not found
bindings.target.mk:97: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bindings/src/serialport.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bindings/src/serialport.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-        gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.4.39
gyp ERR! command "/opt/node/bin/node" "/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-    gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings
gyp ERR! node -v v4.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Linux 3.4.39
npm ERR! argv "/opt/node/bin/node" "/opt/node/bin/npm" "install" "serialport"
npm ERR! node v4.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ ||     node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install script 'prebuild-install --tag-prefix     @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the @serialport/bindings package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs @serialport/bindings
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls @serialport/bindings
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/node/npm-debug.log
```

last part of the log file

```
5807 info install prebuild-install@5.3.3
5808 info postinstall prebuild-install@5.3.3
5809 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/prebuild-install-da7fa1c0b3187458.lock for /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/node_modules/prebuild-install
5810 verbose about to build /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings
5811 info build /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings
5812 info linkStuff @serialport/bindings@8.0.6
5813 silly linkStuff @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 has /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules     as its parent node_modules
5814 verbose linkBins @serialport/bindings@8.0.6
5815 verbose linkMans @serialport/bindings@8.0.6
5816 verbose rebuildBundles @serialport/bindings@8.0.6
5817 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin', '@serialport', 'bindings', 'nan', 'prebuild-install' ]
5818 info install @serialport/bindings@8.0.6
5819 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
5820 info @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 Failed to exec install script
5821 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/serialport-bindings-291f31ff80e6691d.lock for     /home/node/node_modules/serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings
5822 verbose about to build /home/node/node_modules/serialport
5823 verbose unlock done using /root/.npm/_locks/serialport-a4250c37e3372508.lock for     /home/node/node_modules/serialport
5824 verbose stack Error: @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix     @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild`
5824 verbose stack Exit status 1
5824 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
5824 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
5824 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
5824 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>     (/opt/node/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
5824 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
5824 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
5824 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:862:16)
5824 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
5825 verbose pkgid @serialport/bindings@8.0.6
5826 verbose cwd /home/node
5827 error Linux 3.4.39
5828 error argv "/opt/node/bin/node" "/opt/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "serialport"
5829 error node v4.9.1
5830 error npm  v2.15.11
5831 error code ELIFECYCLE
5832 error @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@     || node-gyp rebuild`
5832 error Exit status 1
5833 error Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install script 'prebuild-install --tag-prefix     @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild'.
5833 error This is most likely a problem with the @serialport/bindings package,
5833 error not with npm itself.
5833 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
5833 error     prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild
5833 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
5833 error     npm bugs @serialport/bindings
5833 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
5833 error
5833 error     npm owner ls @serialport/bindings
5833 error There is likely additional logging output above.
5834 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

make by default is not installed in this version, 
any suggestions are welcome, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your nodejs

> npm WARN engine serialport@8.0.6: wanted: {"node":">=**8.6.0**"} (current:     {"node":"**4.9.1**","npm":"2.15.11"})

your current version do not understand ES6 syntax

> ```
> const { hostname, port, protocol, auth, path } = url.parse(opts.url)
>       ^
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My solution: I got more specific about which version of nodejs I was using. I had the latest release (at this writing) 13.8 and I had the same problems as the OP.

So I installed nvm and started using it to pick my nodejs.

```
$ nvm install --lts 
$ nvm use --lts
Now using node v12.16.0
```

The current Long Term Support version (at this writing) is 12.6. I redid `npm install` for the app and after that I had no problems with the serial port. Theoretically, I could have kept nvm'installing different version of nodejs until I got the one that worked.